# How to make a regexp that results in the original text and a modified version?

Tags: regex

How would you build a regular expression that keeps the original text, and appends a modified version of the original text? For example, append a copy of the following text after a "|" with non-alphanumeric characters removed, and spaces replaced with dashes.

This:

```
Hi. My name is Nick.
This: Is the second line!
```

Becomes this:

```
Hi. My name is Nick.|Hi-My-name-is-Nick
This: Is the second line?|This-Is-the-second-line
```

Comment: usually you use a capture group and then reference it with `\1` or `$1` (where 1 is the number of the capture group).  It would be more helpful if you mention what language this is

Comment: The `Becomes this`'s second line changed from the `This`'s second line!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript version:

```
var s = "Hi. My name is Nick.\nThis is the second line!\n";
var replaced = s.replace(/.+/g, function(m) {
  return m + '|' + m.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]+/ig, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-');
} );
console.log(replaced);
```

output:

```
Hi. My name is Nick.|Hi-My-name-is-Nick
This is the second line!|This-is-the-second-line
```

Comment: couple caveats about this.. 1) you make the assumption that non-alphanumeric stuff will be prefixed or suffixed by a space. So this would improperly swap "foo.bar" with "foo-bar" instead of returning "foobar".  2) on the note of alphanumeric.. well, he said alphanumeric, not "word" chars. so `\W` is going to preserver "foo_bar" when it should be returning "foobar"

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the underscore. I've updated my Java answer with the regex `(\W|_)`.

Comment: @CrayonViolent, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

... and this is the php version

```
$string = "Hi. My name is Nick.";
$string = $string.'|'.preg_replace('~\s~','-',preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9\s]~i','',$string));
```

... and a js version

```
var string = "Hi. My name is Nick.";
string = string+'|'+string.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi,'').replace(/\s/g,'-');
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** *Now eliminates punctuation as specified by OP. This also properly considers underscores as punctuation, by using the regex `(\W|_)`, instead of just `\W` (with thanks to @CrayonViolent).*

---

This is how you could do it in Java, using regex. I am *not* using regex for the duplication. Instead I'm just appending the original string (plus "|") to the output buffer, and appending the replacement after that.

```
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

/**
   <P>{@code java DupLinesChangeSpaceToDashInDup}</P>
 **/
public class DupLinesChangeSpaceToDashInDup  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      //input
         String sLS = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
         StringBuilder inputBldr = new StringBuilder().
            append("Hi. My name is Ni__ck.").append(sLS).
            append("This is the second line!").append(sLS);
         String[] textInputArr = inputBldr.toString().split(sLS);

      //config
         //"": Dummy search string, to reuse matcher
         Matcher mtchrNonWordChar = Pattern.compile("(\\W|_)").matcher("");

      //go
         StringBuffer rplcmntBfr = new StringBuffer();
         for(String lineText : textInputArr)  {
            rplcmntBfr.append(lineText).append("|");

            String[] wordArr = lineText.split(" ");

            for(int i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++)  {
               String s = wordArr[i];
               rplcmntBfr.append(mtchrNonWordChar.reset(s).replaceAll(""));
               if(i < wordArr.length - 1)  {
                  rplcmntBfr.append("-");
               }
            }
            rplcmntBfr.append(sLS);
         }

      System.out.println(rplcmntBfr);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java DupLinesChangeSpaceToDashInDup
Hi. My name is Ni__ck.|Hi-My-name-is-Nick
This is the second line!|This-is-the-second-line
```

Comment: he asked that non-alphanumeric (excluding spaces) be stripped.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch that. A completely different (and luckily simpler and shorter) approach was needed. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

> keeps the original text,

This step is trivial as you can just append the result to the original text. If you mean 'keeps the original match' then surround the match with braces `()` and this then will be group 1 referenced by \1 or $1 depending on the language.

> append a ... with non-alphanumeric characters removed, and spaces replaced with dashes.

This is easiest done in two steps:

**1) Replace spaces with dashes**

Match = `\s`

Replace = `-`

This will replace `hello how     are you` with `hello-how-----are-you`

If you want to replace contiguous spaces with a single `-` then use

Match = `\s+`
Replace = `-`

**2) Remove non-alphanumeric**

Match = `[^A-Za-z0-9]`

Replace = `''`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with Perl.

There are three parts.

1) Print the original string followed by a `|`.

```
print "$_|";
```

2) Substitute non-alphanumeric characters with a single `-`.

```
 s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/-/g
```

3) Remove the last `-` with

```
s/[-]$//
```

Some examples-

```
$ echo -n "Hi. My name is Nick." | perl -pe 'print "$_|"; s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/-/g' 
  | perl -pe 's/[-]$//'
Hi. My name is Nick.|Hi-My-name-is-Nick


$ echo -n "This: Is the second line?" | perl -pe 'print "$_|"; s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/-/g' 
  | perl -pe 's/[-]$//'
This: Is the second line?|This-Is-the-second-line
```